# How to create a lanelet2 map for Autoware.Auto AVP demo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**[My question is wrongly originated from [Autoware.Auto's gitlab](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/1018#note_554501591)]**

Hi everyone, I'll try to be as brief as possible. 
[My area](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/21.04178/105.82906) and the trajectory I want to create using lanelet2_global_planner is as follows: [idea of a simple semantic map](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1faujOTiIptoRAj3EKZMYDgDSduhHG4Ys/view?usp=sharing). And my idea to draw semantic map using JOSM: [idea to draw](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yUKGgSfOEQ0pAKd7jOMYc-AJUIw0C266/view?usp=sharing)

After looking into `autonomoustuff_parking_lot.osm` of the AVP demo, the `lanelet2_global_planner` C++ code, I have known that:

- The .osm map has to have an `area` that has`parking_accesses` which lists parking accesses by ids
- Each parking access is a relation that has `type` of `multipolygon` (the `relation` of multiple `way` members with `role` as `outer`), and lists all relevant `parking_spot` in `parking_spots` tag
- Each `parking_spot` has to be a `multipolygon`, and rectangle in shape to be exact, formed from 5 points, where last point stays very close to the first point.

I opened autonomoustuff_parking_lot.osm in JOSM with Imagery, searched for parking_accesse s, parking_slot s by IDs to visually see what they are. But that gives me ununified rules. Sometimes a parking_spot is really a rectangular parking spot, but some times it's like this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CsqZAbVcx5-zo5C0_Jb7GJ40UuwwgSuG/view?usp=sharing)

**What are parking accesses, parking spots literally?**

With manual blind study above, I then created [this .osm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F9ca2JQOdTFPj31MvyA-P_t2zdcoEYK7/view?usp=sharing). However, when re-running the AVP demo, it (and my .pcd point cloud) failed to show up in Rviz, although I had configured `map_publisher`'s `longitude` and `latitude` to be a node's lat and lon in the .osm.

What did I do wrong in the .osm file? **What is the right methodology to start making an .osm map usable for the AVP demo without manually referring to the `autonomoustuff_parking_lot.osm` of the Autoware.Auto?** Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376880/how-to-create-a-lanelet2-map-for-autoware.auto-avp-demo?/) by [congphase](https://answers.ros.org/users/73661/congphase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aleksandr Savel'ev](https://answers.ros.org/users/73343/aleksandr-savel%27ev/) on 2021-04-29**:
Did you also define your osm map lat lon origin in data/autonomoustuff_parking_lot.yaml ?

**Comment by [congphase](https://answers.ros.org/users/73661/congphase/) on 2021-04-29**:
@Aleksandr Savel'ev, I did it bro, as I replied to @mitsudome-r below. So happy.

Anyway, hope my trouble might help you when you come back to global planning after finishing testing sensing with real hardware :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When are planning to do planning from a parking spot to another in Autoware.Auto, the global planner expects to be planned from parking_spot -> parking_access -> lane -> parking_access -> parking_spot.

- parking_spot: The actual space to park, and Autoware.Auto will try to park at the center of this object. It is defined as [lanelet2 Area objects](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/Lanelet2/blob/master/lanelet2_core/doc/LaneletPrimitives.md#area)(`multipolygon` in osm). It should have following tags: `subtype=parking_spot`, `parking_accesses=<list of relevant parking access>`. Autoware.Auto also assumes that the parking spot is rectangle shape with 5 points where first and last point overlap.
- Parking Access Areas: This is used to define free space between parking spot and its nearest lane. Parking planner will use the shape of parking_spot, parking_access, and lanelet to calculate trajectory. Parking Access Areas are defined as [lanelet2 Area objects](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/Lanelet2/blob/master/lanelet2_core/doc/LaneletPrimitives.md#area)(`multipolygon` in osm). It should have following tags: `subtype=parking_access`, `ref_lanelet=<id of the nearest lanelet>`
- Lanelet: Lane objects to define lanes with right bounds and left bounds. See [lanelet2 document](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/Lanelet2/blob/master/lanelet2_core/doc/LaneletPrimitives.md#lanelet) for the details.

If you are familiar with c++, looking into the [global_planner source code](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master/src/planning/lanelet2_global_planner/src/lanelet2_global_planner.cpp) might help you get some idea.

> What did I do wrong in the .osm file?

You have to add multipolygon relation to define parking_spots. You also have to define parking_access area as well. Although you don't have any "gaps" between lanelets and your parking spot, Autoware.Auto expects this object to find out the connection between lanelets and parking spots so you can perhaps create one that is overlapping with the parking_spot. Also,  it seems like you are trying to drive through lanes, in that case, you might not need to define parking spots at all.

If you still don't see a map in RVIZ, I doubt there is something wrong with configuration of the origin when loading the map.

---

Originally posted by [mitsudome-r](https://answers.ros.org/users/41790/mitsudome-r/) with karma: 231 on 2021-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [congphase](https://answers.ros.org/users/73661/congphase/) on 2021-04-29**:
Thank you, Mr. @mitsudome-r, I eventually created a map that trajectories were successfully planned, a day after I asked this question, but I didn't have time to post an update here. Here's my result [link](https://tinyurl.com/4y728szr)

The main reason why I met confusions about figuring out the rules is:

> I opened autonomoustuff_parking_lot.osm in JOSM with Imagery, searched for parking_accesse s, parking_slot s by IDs to visually see what they are. But that gives me ununified rules. Sometimes a parking_spot is really a rectangular parking spot, but some times it's like this

Searching by IDs in JOSM shows highlighted "objects" (nodes, ways...) corresponding to that ID. Those objects are not the parts that form the corresponding parking spot. Instead, they contain that ID as sub-string(s) in their tag values. The appropriate way to navigate to an interested object is demonstrated as [link](https://bit.ly/3aPeDl9). Those who're getting familiar with JOSM can refer.

**Comment by [Aleksandr Savel'ev](https://answers.ros.org/users/73343/aleksandr-savel%27ev/) on 2021-05-12**:
Hello, @congphase . Do you use ssc_interface and vehicle_kinematic_state topic respectively to start lanelet2_global_planner_node ?

**Comment by [congphase](https://answers.ros.org/users/73661/congphase/) on 2021-05-17**:
Hi @Aleksandr Savel'ev. Sorry for the late response. Yes I did. Both of them are used during the lanelet2_global_planner start.

**Comment by [rugved](https://answers.ros.org/users/75152/rugved/) on 2021-07-07**:
What is the "cad_id" and how to find out "ref_lanelet" and "parking_accesses" number to provide it in the relation?

**Comment by [congphase](https://answers.ros.org/users/73661/congphase/) on 2021-07-07**:
@rugved "parking_accesses" is a tag that exists in a relation of type "lanelet" or type "parking_slot", it holds the IDs of the relations of type " parking_access". So you just need to determine the parking accesses (the one multipolygon between a parking slot and the associated lanelet), look for its relation ID, and insert it to the value string of the "parking_accesses" tag in "lanelet" and " parking_slot" relations. This should make the global planner work.

I don't know what cad_id means. cad_id is not quite important for global planner, if I'm not wrong. So you can try skipping it to see if all works.

**Comment by [rugved](https://answers.ros.org/users/75152/rugved/) on 2021-07-07**:
Thanks for the quick response @congphase, really appreciate it. The thing is in the map you provided above, the relation id (-99805, -99807,-99808) has a parking access id as -99786. However, the relation id -99786 is not present in the map. Am I missing any links here?

**Comment by [congphase](https://answers.ros.org/users/73661/congphase/) on 2021-07-07**:
@rugved I don't have a computer now. It's midnight in Vietnam, my country, at the moment. I'll check and reply to you in the next morning.

**Comment by [rugved](https://answers.ros.org/users/75152/rugved/) on 2021-07-07**:
Thank you, appreciate it.Also, what is the center in parking spot relation? How did you provide those values? Were you able get the elevation from JOSM or added manually after?

**Comment by [congphase](https://answers.ros.org/users/73661/congphase/) on 2021-07-07**:
@rugved You're right, it's not in the map. There are 2 parking accesses in my map: `-99828` and `-99806`.


As I remember, JOSM will assign objects with different **negative** IDs every time you save the .osm map without uploading to OSM server. Only uploading to OSM server makes all object ID **positive** and **permanent**. So this must be the reason for the absence of `-99786`. Understanding this, you'll just have to make sure the .osm text of the objects closely reflect the relationship parking spot <--> parking access <--> lanelet, then it's okay.


For me, maybe the global planner only expects the relationship related to one parking access, i.e `-99828` to work well, I skipped to check all the .osm text again.

**Comment by [congphase](https://answers.ros.org/users/73661/congphase/) on 2021-07-07**:
@rugved About the centers in the parking spot relations. I just used the mouse to drag and copied the parking spots of the Autoware.Auto sample map and pasted in my map, to make sure it's perfectly a rectangle. Other than that, I didn't care much. You can take a look at [code implementation](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master/src/planning/lanelet2_global_planner/src/lanelet2_global_planner.cpp) for how the global planner parses the .osm map to figure things out.

**Comment by [rugved](https://answers.ros.org/users/75152/rugved/) on 2021-07-08**:
@congphase Thank you for the answer, I figured out about the centers, In the JOSM after selecting a center node for Multi-polygon parking then View - > Advance info would give a node id which can be provided in the center id. This is true for parking_accesses and parking_spots relations as well.